# TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable - with the while

Tags: python-3.x

Error occurs only after the execution of the while, that is, only after the condition is not met the first time, if all conditions are met, the code runs to the end, without displaying the error if seq0 in list:

TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

[Error occurs after the 2nd execution of the code through the while](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Axan.png)

```
import random
from time import sleep
print('='*50)
print('''\033[1;30;43m HIT AND SEQUENCE OF 4 NUMBERS FROM 1 TO 5 \033[m
\033[1;30;43m   CHOSEN BY PC WITHOUT REPEATING NUMBERS  \033[m ''')
print('='*50)

while True:
    list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    random.shuffle(list)
    list.pop()
    print(f' a lista é {list}')
    right = 0
    while right != 4:
        print('=' * 50)
        player = int(input('\033[7;30;42mChoice the first number from 1 to 5.....\033[m '))
        seq0 = player
        player = int(input('\033[7;30;42mChoice the second number 1 to 5.........\033[m '))
        seq1 = player
        player = int(input('\033[7;30;42mChoice the third number 1 to 5..........\033[m '))
        seq2 = player
        player = int(input('\033[7;30;42mChoice the last number 1 to 5...........\033[m '))
        seq3 = player
        sequence = (seq0, seq1, seq2, seq3)
        print(f'\n\033[1;30;43m      HIS SEQUENCE WAS {sequence}\033[m')
        print('=' * 50)
        nout = 0
        sleep(2)
        if seq0 not in list:
            nout += 1
            #print(f'O número {seq0} não consta na lista')
        if seq1 not in list:
            nout += 1
            #print(f'O número {seq1} não consta na lista')
        if seq2 not in list:
            nout += 1
            #print(f'O número {seq2} não consta na lista')
        if seq3 not in list:
            nout += 1
            #print(f'O número {seq3} não consta na lista')
        print(f'\033[7;30;43m You have {nout} numbers outside the list \033[m\n')
        for sequence, list in zip(sequence, list):
            if sequence == list:
                right += 1
        print(f'\033[7;30;43m {right} numbers in correct position \033[m\n')
    attempts = 0
    if right >= 4:
        attempts += 1
    elif right == 4:
        print('LET´S PLAY AGAIN?')
        break
    print(f'\033[7;30;42m THERE WERE {attempts} ATTEMPTS TO RIGHT THE SEQUENCE \033[m')
    print('='*50)
```

What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

The block of code that is causing your issue is

```
for sequence, list in zip(sequence, list):
    ...
```

You have variables `sequence` and `list` defined above inside and outside your while loop. When you reach the for loop, it is redefining the variables to an `int` rather their previous data structures. You just need to rename your loop variables to something different

```
for seq, lt in zip(sequence, list):
    ...
```

Additionally `list` is a built-in function name. Shadowing it is ill-advised and your variable should be named something different